# didSelectRowAtIndex not being called for WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I have created a push segue in the storyboard from an  `WKInterfaceTableCell` to another `WKInterfaceController` (called `DetailInterfaceController`).

When I tap on the row,  `didSelectRowAtIndex` is not being called.

Does anybody know where I am going wrong, and how I can pass the string?

**TableInterfaceController**

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` `print` statement is not called

```
@IBOutlet var table: WKInterfaceTable!
var objectsArray = ["1","2","3"]
var object: String!

override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    self.object = self.objectsArray[rowIndex]

    print(" object title: \(self.object)")
}


override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {
    // You may want to set the context's identifier in Interface Builder and check it here to make sure you're returning data at the proper times

    // Return data to be accessed in ResultsController
    return self.object
}
```

**DetailsInterfaceController**

The label is not set

```
@IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Make sure data was passed properly and update the label accordingly
    if let val: String = context as? String {
        self.label.setText(val)
    } else {
        self.label.setText("")
    }
    // Configure interface objects here.
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why it's not called:**

It's normal for `table:didSelectRowAtIndex:` to not be called since you used a storyboard segue.  From the [`WKInterfaceController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/table:didSelectRowAtIndex:) documentation:

> If you connected an action method to the table in your storyboard file, **WatchKit does not call this method**.

**How to pass the selected row data:**

You should use `contextForSegueWithIdentifier:inTable:rowIndex:` to return the context for the selected row:

```
override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    if segueIdentifier == "someSegueIdentifier" {
        return objectsArray[rowIndex]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it turns out that I had unchecked the "selectable" box of my row item in the storyboard

[image: overview]

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. It was driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `table:didSelectRowAtIndex:` won't be worked by another one obvious reason: `WKInterfaceButton` is placed on the row and the user taps on it. In this case, the `tap` event will only be fired only for button. The delegate method won't work. The solution is removing `WKInterfaceButton` from the row of `WKInterfaceTable`